# VM3 Order Numbers

Tags: joomla-2.5, virtuemart, id

We print out the admin order confirmation e-mail for our clients. The order number (example - 8ae20135) is too confusing for them. The current system is Joomla 2.5 / VM3. On the old version of Joomla 1.5 / VM1 the order number was simple (examples - 1, 2, 3... etc).

Is there any way to change this? Or is the order number stuck like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin does the job, order numbers are customisable through this - http://extensions.virtuemart.net/vm-orders/order-number-plugin-detail